# Изменение элементов виджета через iframe

Tags: iframe, виджет, design

Всем привет. Решаю такую головоломку. 
Есть вот такой плеер:

```
<iframe width="100%" height="60" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fscazy%2F&hide_cover=1&mini=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Выглядит так:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="60" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fscazy%2F&hide_cover=1&mini=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

Мне необходимо его также через iframe воткнуть на сайт но при этом избавиться от черного бэкграунда контейнера и его рамки. 
Поковыряв в просмотре кода смог только убрать черный фон.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как думаете возможно ли изменить дизайн виджета через iframe как я хочу это сделать и поставить его на сайт? спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Изменить стилистику через **iframe** не получиться, так как, в данном случае он всего лишь обращается к странице сайта, на которой уже прописана вся стилистика.

Вы можете либо создать страницу с проигрывателем на своём сайте и там менять стилистику, либо просить у администрации сайта сделать новый стиль для проигрывателя, либо воспользоваться существующими.

Максимум, что могу Вам предложить - это проигрыватель с белым фоном:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="60" src="https://www.mixcloud.com/widget/iframe/?feed=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.mixcloud.com%2Fscazy%2Fthe-haze-mix-2%2F&hide_cover=1&mini=1&light=1" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```